# Jenkins pipeline not failing based on batch exit code

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having trouble with a Jenkins pipeline that is not failing when a called batch file fails. I have checked the batch file, it returns a non-zero status code, but somehow this seems to be not considered. Does anyone of you have a hint for me?

desired pipeline

```
node {
  stage('1'){
    dir('_src') {
      bat 'call test.bat'
    }
  }
}
```

Calling the batch in cmd window results in the following

```
>call test.bat
INFO: Started ...
ERROR
Press any key to continue . . . 
>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
2
```

I also used the following pipeline for testing

```
node {
  stage('1'){
    dir('_src') {
      bat '''call test.bat
      echo %ERRORLEVEL%'''
    }
  }
}
```

... with this output

```
C:\_src>call test.bat 
INFO: Started ...
ERROR
Press any key to continue . . . 
2
```

Still, the pipeline is not failing. Any ideas?

Comment: Does `bat '''exit 2'''` work? Maybe you have a problem because there's no `step{ }` inside your stage.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
node {
  stage('1'){
    dir('_src') {
      bat '''call test.bat
      exit %ERRORLEVEL%'''
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to explicitly exit with `exit %ERRORLEVEL%` even though the batch file already exits with this errorlevel? I was expecting that when the batch file exits with a non-zero status code, the stage will automatically fail. Is this not the case?

Comment: you use 'call' so the wrapping shell is probably not getting the exit code

Comment: Even without the 'call', the result is the same and the stage does not fail. Probably it will work with the additional exit, but to be honest,  this is really not nice if I have to do it for each and every bat statement...

Comment: I agree, but it has probably something to do with the 'bat' the may have a bug... And it works...

Comment: I tried this, it only seems to work with the `call` in place. Without it I get no error propagated.

Answer (score 0):

You only write an echo, not actually doing a return/ exit. Try to add a concrete `Exit 0` or in your case `Exit 2` in your script.

Comment: The echo is only there for debugging purposes. I neither wanted to add the echo, nor the exit in the first case, but was expecting the stage to fail when the batch file fails, i.e. exits with a non-zero exit code